# Can't clean URL from custom query parameters

Tags: database, uri

I have a client whose company has different branches. The data are retrieved from a DB (not the Drupal one). 
For example, the url `mydrupalsite.com/branch?branchID=1` should lead to `mydrupalsite.com/branch/1`, `mydrupalsite.com/branch?branchID=23` to `mydrupalsite.com/branch/23`. 
I have created a page for the branches, at which the content will change slightly and dynamically, according to the branch we choose.
 I've tried using `InboundPathProcessorInterface()`, `OutboundPathProcessorInterface()` and `PathProcessorAlias()`, but I can't get rid of the query `?branchID=23`, so I only get `mydrupalsite.com/branch/23?branchID=23`.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We love to help you. This sounds more like a server-side redirect issue. From `.htaccess`. Maybe you can elaborate a bit how these pages are built and how they pull their content exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We have built a custom Page (/branch) and we want to access that specific page and change its contents, according to the DB data through a menu callback. So, basically, the only things that will be changing are the path and the title. So, I am required to rewrite every URL of this form (mydrupalsite.com/branch?branchID=1) to mydrupalsite.com/branch/$1, and all of them should lead to /branch page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Redirection Rules in your .htaccess file to achieve this task.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/branch)$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} branchID=(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) /branch/%1?  [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope, this helps you.